# Design for a C++ API combining synchronous and asynchronous operations

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I am designing a C++ API which exposes both synchronous and asynchronous operations. All operations may fail and must report the failure. The asynchronous operations must provide a way to execute a continuation when they complete. I am trying to design the API in the most readable and consistent manner.

This is an example illustrating the design I have for now:

```
#include <memory>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

class Error {
public:
    Error(int c, string desc) : code(c), description(desc) {} 

    int code;
    string description;
};

template<typename T>
class Callback {
public:
    virtual void completed(const T& result, unique_ptr<Error> error) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class PrintCallback : public Callback<T> {
public:
    void completed(const T& result, unique_ptr<Error> error) override {
        if (nullptr != error) {
            printf("An error has occured. Code: %d Description: %s\n", 
                    error->code, error->description.c_str());
        } else {
            printf("Operation completed successfully. Result: %s\n", 
                    to_string(result).c_str());
        }
    }
};

class API {
public:
    void asyncOperation(shared_ptr<Callback<int>> callback) {
        thread([callback]() {
            callback->completed(5, nullptr);
        }).detach();
    }

    int syncOperation(unique_ptr<Error>& error) {
        return 5;
    }

    void asyncFailedOperation(shared_ptr<Callback<int>> callback) {
        thread([callback]() {
            callback->completed(-1, unique_ptr<Error>(new Error(222, "Async Error")));
        }).detach();
    }

    int syncFailedOperation(unique_ptr<Error>& error) {
        error = unique_ptr<Error>(new Error(111, "Sync Error"));
        return -1;
    }
};
```

I don’t like the use of use of the error out parameter for synchronous operations and the inconsistency between synchronous and asynchronous signatures.
I’m debating two alternatives:

1. Treat synchronous operations as if they are asynchronous and let them accept a Callback to return their result / failure by. This approach is more consistent across synchronous and asynchronous operations and looks a bit cleaner. On the other hand, it’s feels a bit weird to have a simple synchronous operation work with a Callback.
2. Use `std::promise` and `std::future`, and use exceptions to report failures. For asynchronous operations, an `std::future` would be returned and its `get()` will throw in case of failures. Synchronous operations will simply throw in case of failures. This approach feels much cleaner, as error handling does not clatter the method signatures, and exceptions are the standard way to do error handling in C++. However, to get the result I’ll have to call `future::get()` so if I don’t want to block, then I have to fire up another thread to wait for the result. It may also be important that the continuation for the asynchronous operation runs on the thread that actually sets the result on the `std::promise`. This approach is the accepted answer to this question - [Synchronous and ASynchronous APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093176/synchronous-and-asynchronous-apis).

I’m wondering:

1. If the extra thread in alternative #2 can be avoided.
2. If the cons of alternative #2 outweigh its pros (especially the extra thread).
3. If there’s another approach that I haven’t considered.
4. Which approach would be considered the best pick for readability and consistency.

Thanks!

Comment: As it stands, the question is too broad for Stack Overflow. You could write an entire book on API design! :) However, I do have one nitpick: *"exceptions are the standard way to do error handling in C++"* - No, they are not. Depending on the context, error codes or assertions are often cleaner.

Comment: The [codereview.se] site is more appropriate for questions about improving existing working code.  I suggest you flag your question for migration there, after consulting their [Help Center](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @ChristianHackl I feel this should be a pretty focused design problem. I tried to present a consistency problem between async and sync methods in regard to error handling, where I got with my research on how to solve it (the different alternatives) and my concerns with them.

Comment: @TobySpeight The attached code is working, but it’s just there to illustrate the callback approach, not to be reviewed. I could remove it if it distracts from the real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Q: If the extra thread in alternative #2 can be avoided.
- A: One way to avoid extra threads is to use a thread pool together with a task queue. The approach still uses extra threads but the number of threads is sort of fixed system wise, rather than proportional to the number of tasks ever created.
- Q: If the cons of alternative #2 outweigh its pros (especially the extra thread).
- A: I don't think so.
- Q: If there’s another approach that I haven’t considered.
- A: Yes. The best approach in my opinion is to make everything async, provide similar API to boost::asio, leverage on boost::asio::io_service and lambda functions, and implement a thread pool and task queue. You may implement sync as a wrapper over async as follows: Make an async call and wait for an std::condition_variable. The callback of your async call signals that condition_variable.
- Q: Which approach would be considered the best pick for readability and consistency.
- A: Async code is not going to be as readable as sync code. If readability is really really important for you, give up async. On the other hand, if you want async and consistency, make everything async as I outlined above.

In addition to that, in my opinion you should not implement your own Error class. Have a look at std::error_code (and also error_condition, error_category). A nice article is http://blog.think-async.com. Someone already figured it out for you.

Comment: Thanks! `std::error_code` looks like the way to go instead of my Error class, and the blog post you linked is really helpful. I started reading up about boost’s `io_service`, but in general, making each operation a class of its own is an interesting approach to consider. Right now I’m leaning towards using `std::future`.